# Is there a built-in Capybara method to click on an element multiple times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I have a form with a '+' icon to increase the number value inside of another tag.

So with Capybara I can just click on it like this:

```
all('.qty-input')[0].find('.more').click
```

But I want to be able to set the amount of clicks through a variable. I tried doing this but it raises an error because click does not accept any parameters.

```
all('.qty-input')[0].find('.more').click(number_of_clicks)
```

I think I can create a simple method to this, like this, but is it necessary? Doesn't Capybara have anything built-in for several clicks?

```
def multiple_clicks element, number_of_clicks
   number_of_clicks.times{|n| element.click}
end
```

Edit:

The original code I put there was

```
def multiple_clicks element, number_of_clicks
   number_of_clicks.map{|n| element.click}
end
```

Which doesn't make sense, so I edited it using `times` instead of `map` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Capybara doesn't have anything like that built-in

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're after, but I did something like this:

```rb
# Get elements (adjust to your own circumstances)
plus_buttons = all('.btn')

# Nice way to click a number of times
3.times { plus_buttons[0].click }

# Or set number of times as a variable
number = 7
number.times { plus_buttons[0].click }
```